# How do I find a value between two strings?

Tags: java

How would I "find" and "get" a value between two strings?

ie: `<a>3</a>`

I'm reading a file to find the location of `<a>`, where that starts, then it will stop reading when it finds `</a>` The value I want to return is "3".

Using JRE 6

Comment: A regular expression will work, FSVO "work". However, HTML/XML parsing (which are related but different) should really be done with an appropriate tool (hopefully one that supports a powerful selector language).

Comment: exact duplicate of [Searching for a tag, then saving text between tag as a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093716/searching-for-a-tag-then-saving-text-between-tag-as-a-variable)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your two main options are:

1) **preferred but potentially complicated**: using an XML/HTML parser and getting the text within the first "a" element.  e.g. using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) (thanks @alpha123):

```java
Jsoup.parse("<a>3</a>").select("a").first().text(); // => "3"
```

2) **easier but not very reliable**: using a regular expression to extract the characters between the `<a>` and `</a>` strings.  e.g.:

```java
String s = "<a>3</a>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a>(.*?)</a>")
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); // => "3"
}
```

Comment: and how would I do the easy way?

Comment: as long as the tags are not nested the regex is reliable

Comment: @ratchet freak That is as long as nobody ever writes `< a>` or encodes some part, or... Not that reliable really

Answer (score 6):

[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) will do this easily.

```
String title = Jsoup.parse("<a>3</a>").select("a").first().text();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex:

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<a>(.*)</a>");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            // matched text: regexMatcher.group(i)
            // match start: regexMatcher.start(i)
            // match end: regexMatcher.end(i)
        }
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

But, if your input is HTML, you should really consider using an HTML parser.

Comment: ...Why are you wrapping this in a try block?

Comment: The code's generated by [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), but if there's nothing wrong with the syntax (like in this case) it's not necessary.