# Java Regex Extract String between two Strings

Tags: java, android, regex, string, illegalstateexception

### The problem

I have a pattern like this "Nom for ? oscars" or "Nom for 2 Golden Globes. Nom for ? oscars. 30 wins 18 nominations" And I want to determine the ? with regex, so the amount of oscars.

### What I tried

It seems like there

Corresponding to this questions: [Extract string between two strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597303/extract-string-between-two-strings-in-java) and

[How do I find a value between two strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129111/how-do-i-find-a-value-between-two-strings) I tried this pattern:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("for(.*?)Oscar");
```

Next I tried this following this question: [Java - Best way to grab ALL Strings between two Strings? (regex?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255353/java-best-way-to-grab-all-strings-between-two-strings-regex)

```
  final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("Nom") +"(.*?)"+ Pattern.quote("Oscar"));
```

The rest of my code:

```
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Nom for 3 Oscar");
    while(matcher.find()){

    }
Log.d("Test", matcher.group(1));
```

All of these pattern result in this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far

I think I just oversee something very simple.

Can you guys help me ?

### Edit

---

So the problem was that I call matcher.group(1) after the loop. I missunderstood the working of the find method. However this code is working indeed, when i call matcher.group(1) inside the loop.

```
   final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("for(.*?)Oscar");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Nom for 3 Oscar");
        while(matcher.find()){
         Log.d("Test", matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I write test as in [Extract string between two strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597303/extract-string-between-two-strings-in-java) and this is working. I think Your input string don't matches:

```
 @Test
        public void regex() {
            String str = "Nom for 3 Oscar, dom for 234235 Oscars";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("for(.*?)Oscar");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
    3 
 234235
```

After my answer You edited Your question and I see, in Your input String "oscar" starts with lowecase "o", in Pattern with uppercase "O".

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern,

```
\w+\s+\w+\s(\d+)\s\w+
```

Try this,

```
String str = "Nom for 3 Oscar";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s+(\\d+)\\s+\\w+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    Log.d("Test", matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Why only allow 1 space around number, but 1+ spaces between `Nom` and `for`?

Comment: I cant compile this since I get the error illegal escape character

Comment: @Andreas It was a typo. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Sadly I still get IllegalStateException with no successfull match so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
"\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s+(\\w+)\\s+\\w+"
```

Test code :

```
String str = "Nom for you Oscar";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s+(\\w+)\\s+\\w+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Do you want to intercept third strings?

Comment: I edited my question :) yes i want to intecept other strings as well. Thanks for your help ! Sadly this code doesnt work :(